# OpenVPN Connect incorrect profile configuration (Error message: crypto_alg: SHA3-512: not found)

Tags: vpn, sha, openvpn, sha-3, openvpn-connect

I used to connect to the server through OpenVPN Connect without any issues when I had imported previous profile in .opvn format.

My boss had to reestablish server and while doing so he also must have changed something because my current profile he has given me throws this error during import:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5clp.png)

They only significant difference I noticed is that the previous profile used to include:
"auth SHA256"
and the current one includes:
"auth SHA3-512".

I also tried changing it to "auth SHA512", but sadly to no avail.

As far as I know I'm the only one encountering this problem. My boss has Mac so he can't really help me from what he said because I use Windows 11.

Although others with Windows had no issues...

I tried importing profile from .ovpn file to OpenVPN Connect so that I could connect to the server.